# Kosel after Candle Lighting

Tags: shabbat, candle-lighting, kotel-western-wall

I noticed that in Israel many women accompany their husbands' in taxis to the Kosel after they already lit the Shabbos Candles. Is this permissible? And if so, why (or how)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When they light candles they have in mind not to be Mekabel Shabbos until the Zeman.

Comment: So is that legit. Can women do it here as well? And can men do the same when saying Mizmor Shir

Comment: Realize that in Yerushalyim they light 40 minutes prior to Shkia. It can be done anywhere, however only up to the real Zeman. Regarding a man once he said Mizmor Shir I never heard that a man can do that.

Comment: @yydl, I understand that some women do it weekly so as to be able to put the matches away after lighting.

Comment: @GershonGold - Sometimes when I daven at two minyanim on Friday night (early and late), I will consider the early tefillot to be like a tefilat nedavah, and I have in mind not to be mekabel shabbos until the second one just in case there is some more melachah that needs doing. This includes Mizmor Shir. And what's problematic about it? It is just saying Tehillim.

Comment: How do you know this is what they do?